# return set amount of characters after splitting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, return

I have a data frame where one column contains strings in the following format:

`[{"assignedAgentId": "15", "assignedFullName": "Virtual Assistant", "interactionTime": "2023-03-15 18:39:42.443+0000", "interactiveSequence": 1, "dialogId": "fcf12345-e2d-4e2c-be5t-ed2bcf1831gh"}, {"assignedAgentId": "16", "assignedAgentFullName": "S", "interactionTime": "2023-03-16 08:00:50.500+0000", "dialogId": "fcf12345-e2d-4e2c-be5t-ed2bcf1831gh"}]`

I want to be able to extract into a new column the first 19 characters after the last occurrence of "interactionTime" so given the above example it would return:

"2023-03-16 08:00:50"

I know that I can split a string from the right using:

```
result=line.rsplit('interactionTime',1)
print('This is the result:', result[1])
```

However I'm unsure how to return the first 19 characters after and store them in a new dataframe column called "Interaction Time"

I have tried:

```
df2=df1['interaction Time'].str.split("InteractionTime", n=1, expand=True)
```

however this returns a column of Nans.

Comment: Your input is unclear, you say "strings" but show a list of dictionaries. Please provide a reproducible DataFrame constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
data = ['2023-03-15 18:39:42.443+0000', '2023-03-16 08:00:50.500+0000']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['interactionTime'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2['InterationTime'] = df['interactionTime'].str[:19]

print(df2)
```

output

```
        InterationTime
0  2023-03-15 18:39:42
1  2023-03-16 08:00:50

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

That column seems to be a list in perfectly valid `JSON` format.

You could load the Json into a valid Python structure (a list of dicts), get the last item (indexing with `[-1]`) and then get elements from start until 19 (`[:19]`) of the `interactionTime` value:

```
import json

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1],
    "weird_col": [
        '[{"assignedAgentId": "15", "assignedFullName": "Virtual Assistant", "interactionTime": "2023-03-15 18:39:42.443+0000", "interactiveSequence": 1, "dialogId": "fcf12345-e2d-4e2c-be5t-ed2bcf1831gh"}, {"assignedAgentId": "16", "assignedAgentFullName": "S", "interactionTime": "2023-03-16 08:00:50.500+0000", "dialogId": "fcf12345-e2d-4e2c-be5t-ed2bcf1831gh"}]'
    ],
})

df['dates'] = df['weird_col'].apply(
    lambda x: json.loads(x)[-1]['interactionTime'][:19]
)
print(df['dates'])
```

This said... Having dealt with timezones, timeoffsets and the like, are you sure you'd like to lose all that juicy information when you have a very nice valid datetime object in there? Of course, you know better, but... dunno... makes me sad when you'd just need to use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['dates'] = df['weird_col'].apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(json.loads(x)[-1]['interactionTime'])
)
print(df['dates'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead parsing them to datetime instances!

- no need to discard sub-second data if it's needed later
- handles multiple timezones (may be very important)
- easy control of display format
- ability to do offset math and more with it

```py
>>> df["interactionTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["interactionTime"])
```

Custom display format

```py
>>> df["interactionTime"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  # custom display
0    2023-03-15 18:39:42
1    2023-03-16 08:00:50
Name: interactionTime, dtype: object
```

Example convenience of math for seconds from a starting date

```py
>>> (df["interactionTime"] - pd.to_datetime("2023-03-01 00:00:00+0000")).dt.total_seconds()
0    1276782.443
1    1324850.500
Name: interactionTime, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extracting the 19 first characters, you should consider changing time format as follows :

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

datas = [{"assignedAgentId": "15", "assignedFullName": "Virtual Assistant", 
         "interactionTime": "2023-03-15 18:39:42.443+0000", "interactiveSequence": 1, 
         "dialogId": "fcf12345-e2d-4e2c-be5t-ed2bcf1831gh"}, 
        {"assignedAgentId": "16", "assignedAgentFullName": "S", 
         "interactionTime": "2023-03-16 08:00:50.500+0000", 
         "dialogId": "fcf12345-e2d-4e2c-be5t-ed2bcf1831gh"}]

# Refactoring to 'records' json format
datas = [{k:[v] for k,v in d.items()} for d in datas]
# List of dataframes
dfx = [pd.read_json(str(dat).replace("'", '"'), orient='records') for dat in datas]
# Convert to specified format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
l=[]
for df in dfx:
    df["Interaction Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, "interactionTime"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    l.append(df)

r = pd.concat(l, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
# Display the two r-columns
print(r[['interactionTime','Interaction Time']])
```

```
                interactionTime     Interaction Time
0  2023-03-15 18:39:42.443+0000  2023-03-15 18:39:42
1  2023-03-16 08:00:50.500+0000  2023-03-16 08:00:50
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone that provided an answer, especially @BorrajaX who pointed out the JSON format.

Using his method gave me an 'string indices must be integers' error however it did help me produce the following which achieves what I need:

```
df["interactions"] = df["interactions"].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
df["interactions"] = df["interactions"].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))

# find the last instance of interactionTime and create a new column with everything after it
new_column_values = []
for interaction in datas2['interactions']:
    interaction_str = json.dumps(interaction)  # convert interaction object to a string
    interaction_time_index = interaction_str.rfind('interactionTime')  # find the last index of interactionTime
    if interaction_time_index != -1:
        new_column_value = interaction_str[interaction_time_index+len('"interactionTime": '):interaction_time_index+len('"interactionTime": ')+19]  # extract everything after interactionTime
        new_column_values.append(new_column_value)
    else:
        new_column_values.append('')  # if interactionTime not found, set value to empty string

# create a new column in the dataframe with the extracted values
df.loc[:, 'new_column'] = new_column_values
```